# Black Screen Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am facing a problem. When I want to change the View for a Tab View Controller, my application gives a black screen.

[image]

And here is my code to change view:

```
let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? HomeViewController

self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Constants.swift:

```
import Foundation

struct Constants {

    struct Storyboard {

        static let homeViewController = "homeVC"

    }
}
```

homeVC is the first View of TabBarController, with the Label.

Comment: try set TabbarViewController id = "homeVC", It will load all tab its have(include ViewController with Label text)

Answer (score 0):

This is my way. I am not using storyboard by the way. I am using xib.

```
let dashboardVc = DashboardTabController()
self.window!.rootViewController = dashboardVc
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
self.window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

and then in dashboardTabController type this one.

```
import UIKit

class DashboardTabController: UITabBarController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dashboardTabBar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstViewController = HomeViewController()

        firstViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "ic_home_24px"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "ic_home_24px"))

        let secondViewController = AddContactViewController()

        secondViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "ic_group_add_24px"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "ic_group_add_24px"))

        let tabBarList = [firstViewController, secondViewController]

        viewControllers = tabBarList
    }
}
```

don't forget in DashBoardTabController xib, implement the UITabBar in bottom. Hopefully it's helpful. Just mention me if you need more help on executing this.

Comment: I have replace class of my first Item view in Storyboard, and then, the simulator not showing a black screen but it's showing right screen with label but without Tab Bar, so I have not yet used your code.

Comment: I think because you are not setting tab bar page in root view controller. But instead you are setting the home page on root. that's why the tab bar is missing